# Guzzle7 multipart/form-data POST not working correctly

Tags: php, web-crawler, guzzle

I'm trying to recreate submitting a form.  But for some reason my POST request does not return the correct page.  Below I have included a raw CURL request which does work, and then my Guzzle code which does not work.

What is the difference between my broken Guzzle code and the working CURL request?

My Guzzle code:

```
    $jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://www.southeastwater.co.uk',
        'cookies' => $jar,
    ]);
    $res = $client->request('GET', '/my-water-supply/my-water-looks-smells-strange/check-your-water-quality-hardness');

    $html = new \simplehtmldom\HtmlDocument($res->getBody());
    $form = $html->find('form.sewForm',1);
    foreach($form->find('input') as $n => $input){
        $x = [
            'name' => $input->name,
            'contents' => $input->value,
        ];
        $post[] = $x;

        if($n == 0){ // This is button field does just manually add it after the first input
            $post[] = [
                'name' => 'Jump',
                'contents' => '10',
            ];
        }
    }


    $post = [
        'multipart/form-data' => $post
    ];

    $res2 = $client->post('/my-water-supply/my-water-looks-smells-strange/check-your-water-quality-hardness', $post);
    echo $res2->getBody();
    // But body is wrong, it's shows HTML as if I had just refreshed the page and not submitted the POST at all.
    exit();
```

Here is the working CURL request:

```
curl 'https://www.southeastwater.co.uk/my-water-supply/my-water-looks-smells-strange/check-your-water-quality-hardness' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0' 
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed 
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------18455269113520999061513576751' 
-H 'Origin: https://www.southeastwater.co.uk' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
-H 'Referer: https://www.southeastwater.co.uk/my-water-supply/my-water-looks-smells-strange/check-your-water-quality-hardness' 
-H 'Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=Tnrx3xY2ia2Dk5fBdi16ppscN3_TeR67OLBDf8mz1WeYzUZIUPLRjXMDUZJbN7uH5oEGZOkDG-m_sf_8waTv3bxfYyEQjiBHSI2HeNFGMMM1' 
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' 
--data-binary $'-----------------------------18455269113520999061513576751\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="__RequestVerificationToken"\r\n\r\nnlEsW1Iccl9L3dc_gNgdRzKO0VKRQxxznr3WV8SiKixyRZRCnlAuvKAZZEvERfJP-Al8wldrb5vSTIbeeZMXh8LSPSy6gTX9bTmQONCKnzg1\r\n-----------------------------18455269113520999061513576751\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Jump"\r\n\r\n10\r\n-----------------------------18455269113520999061513576751\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="WaterHardnessStep10_Postcode.Postcode"\r\n\r\n\r\n-----------------------------18455269113520999061513576751\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="WaterHardnessStep10_Postcode.ContactReason"\r\n\r\n\r\n-----------------------------18455269113520999061513576751\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="WaterHardnessStep10_Postcode.IsPostcodeInSupplyArea"\r\n\r\nFalse\r\n-----------------------------18455269113520999061513576751\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="WaterHardnessStep10_Postcode.SummaryHTML"\r\n\r\n\r\n-----------------------------18455269113520999061513576751\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ufprt"\r\n\r\n674979BCF955C16BD4492455228446D83AF77F393A0590F7C5DFEB8B23D87FC7F5657AB9254637877D139888488F106804F9982255BDCC1895FBD49330FB5DBC2BEB0F5F43ECBCDF1B5441ADAA5C8F5EBC1BBAB24EA9E7E0A21F3429BDB5264E425D439FAB6C4863B68120C0A90C3BF990A5D01CDBA3C88716BFDFF84EABE11F447DA1607D0E3FBF2A2890DFB2420C8C\r\n-----------------------------18455269113520999061513576751--\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

First I feel you are taking a Cookie jar instance but have not set the cookie.

```
$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;
$jar = \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar::fromArray(
    [
        '__RequestVerificationToken' => 'your token ...'
    ],
    'https://www.southeastwater.co.uk'
);
$r = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.southeastwater.co.uk', [
    'cookies' => $jar
]);
```

Also you need to send the thing you want to send as multipart/form-data in multipart key in guzzle.

```
$res2 = $client->post('/my-water-supply/my-water-looks-smells-strange/check-your-water-quality-hardness', [
    'multipart' => $post
    ]
]);
```

### NOTE :

I have assumed `$post` as to be obtained from this step.

```
$post[] = [
                'name' => 'Jump',
                'contents' => '10',
            ];
```

Comment: Thanks it turns out my problem was using:

`$post = [
        'multipart/form-data' => $post
    ];`

Instead i should have been using:

`$post = [
        'multipart' => $post
    ];`

Comment: That is what I have written in answer `Also you need to send the thing you want to send as multipart/form-data in multipart key in guzzle`, see this line